# Linking .lib files in netbeans IDE 7.0

Tags: c, netbeans, cygwin, static-libraries

I am trying to run Cplex from netbeans IDE 7.0 with Cygwin. I want to include .lib files but it takes only .a files. Is there any way to include these .lib files

Answer (score 0):

every lib in Netbeans is linked by pressing the right-button of the mouse on the root of your project. Then, press "Properties" option and then go the "Library" options. In the "Compile" tab go to the "Add Library" button and so link all the libraries you need.

I usually link the cplex.jar library and use it for my needs! Check-out for the system OS (i.e. 64 or 32 bit) and be sure that your ILOG's CPLEX release is "confirmed".